# Creating a custom VStack Initialiser

Tags: ios, swiftui

I want to create an initialiser for a `VStack` that takes my custom enum as it's spacing element. I have this code:

```
enum Styles {
  enum Spacing: CGFloat {
    case one = 4
    case two = 8
    case three = 16
  }
}

extension VStack where Content: View {
  init(
    alignment: HorizontalAlignment = .center,
    spacing: Styles.Spacing? = nil,
    content: () -> Content
  ) {
    self.init(
      alignment: alignment,
      spacing: spacing?.rawValue ?? Styles.Spacing.three.rawValue,
      content: content
    )
  }
}
```

When I use my custom VStack initialiser within a `@ViewBuilder` function, it comes back with the error `Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'`. Here's an example of when that occurs:

```
@ViewBuilder
private func textBlock(
  question: String,
  answer: String
) -> some View {
  VStack(
    alignment: .leading,
    spacing: .three
  ) {
    Text(question)
    Text(answer)
  }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mark your `content` param as `@ViewBuilder`:

`@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content`

Some considerations:

1. Your current implementation of `textBlock` doesn't need to be marked as `@ViewBuilder` (unless you plan to add more views after the `VStack`), so you can remove that.
2. The optional `spacing` parameter will not work at all, because any calls to `VStack(alignment: <something>)` will collide with your signature (since you provide a default value for `spacing`) and the compiler will have no clue as to which initializer should be used. So you'll have to make this one non-optional.